# Create Popup for existing button

Tags: javascript, html, css

edit: i cant edit the original code, since the button and its function is provided by a plugin. If could find the initial JS for the function of the button, i would hide the first one and recreate / modify it myself if thats somehow possible..

I have a button which is already styled and running a javascript function (cant find the code for it).

Is it possible to create a popup for that existing button?

Found this tutorial on how to create a popup on W3

```
<div class="popup w3-text-blue" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to toggle the popup!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
</div>


<style>

.popup {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}


.popup .popuptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -80px;
}



.popup .popuptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent; }

span#myPopup.popuptext.show {
    visibility: visible;

}

</style>


<script>


// When the user clicks the div, open the popup
function myFunction() {
    var popup = document.getElementById('myPopup');
    popup.classList.toggle('show');
}

</script>
```

but cant make it work for an existing button.

All info i have for that button:

```
<button type="button" class="class class2 class3" data-overwrite-fields="1"><i class="fas fa-check fa-fw"></i> Submit</button>
```

(the i class is an svg image)

Is it possible to create a popup for that button or should i move on?

Comment: Can you provide more html "surrounding" that button? Also are you able to edit/modify the html/css of that button?

Comment: Because the button does not have an `id` set, more HTML around/near that button should be provided (*as noted by **John***). This will allow you/us to have JavaScript select that specific button (and not another one on the page). Aside from that, yes it would be possible to remove the existing button and replace it with one that opens a popup.

Comment: Unfortunately no..

There is only the class i already found.

Also no id.

But the class seems specific enough. When i style it with css, it gets edited correctly.

But dont know how if that will help me out.

Basically what im trying to do is, get any reaction out of that button. The button has an important function but acts still after being clicked. As if it was never clicked. (Already tried customizing Active/hover states etc.)

Comment: "*Unfortunately no..*" you cannot provide any additional HTML? Where is the button added to the page? If a plugin is adding the button, it must be adding it to a specific spot on the page and the HTML from that section is what we would need to see to select and replace that button.

Comment: I really cant.
The button is placed next to other 3 buttons which i dont need. (I display:none them.)
The surrounding html is not in any relation to the one of the button.
I copied a section out, a chunk of 10k words. Used notepad++ to search for the class, 12 results without any useful relation

Comment: "*The surrounding html is not in any relation to the one of the button*" I doubt that is true and not posting prevents us from helping you. There are numerous methods to select elements based on their relation to other elements. Parents, siblings, children and even nearby elements can all be used to select and narrow down elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping the button in a div with an onclick for the div, in which you `preventDefault()`, then show your popup, and use JS or jQuery to "click" the button you can't modify.

Something like this:

```
<div onclick="yourOwnFunction">
    <button id="buttonId"></button> <!-- Button you can't change -->
</div>
```

Then:

```
function yourOwnFunction(event){
  showPopup();
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

Note, this assumes that you don't want the button's function to execute before your popup is displayed. If this is the case, once the user does what is needed on your popup, you can then "fire" the button's function with something like this:

```
function whatHappensWhenModalIsClosed(){
  document.getElementById("buttonId").click();
}
```

Comment: Would try it out but i dont really know what to do with that

Answer (score 0):

##### Notes

There are a lack of details in the question that make this a bit tricky. Because the `<button>` in question does not have an `id` set and there appears to be other buttons with potentially the same class, a lot of assumptions have to be made.

Ideally if we know the parent element, we can use that as a selector first to narrow the results, then attempt to select our button. Also, if any siblings or nearby elements have an `id` set, we could use things like [nextElementSibling()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling) or the [closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) methods to grab this specific button.

### Solution

The approach however is to grab all of the *potential* buttons and loop through them. From there, I am checking to make sure the `data-overwrite-fields` attribute is equal to `1` and that the text within the button is equal to `submit` (forced to lower case). Without more information from OP I cannot guarantee these criteria will limit the result to only 1 button, but this should be a useful start for OP to translate into a solution.

The next steps are to copy the button, add a new event listener (as well as the popup element) and then replace the old button with the newly created one.

```js
const _ReplaceButton = () => {
  document.querySelectorAll("button.class.class2.class3").forEach(b => {
    // Because we do not know if there are other buttons with this class,
    // we must try to narrow it down
    if(b.dataset.overwriteFields != "1" || b.innerText.trim().toLowerCase() != "submit") return
    
    // Copy the button and create the popup element
    let newButton = b.cloneNode(true),
    popup = document.createElement("div")

    // Set the event listener for the new button
    newButton.addEventListener("click", myFunction)

    // Set the class and content for the popup
    popup.className = "popup w3-text-blue"
    popup.innerHTML = `<span class="popuptext" id="newPopup">New Button!</span>`

    // Replace the old button
    b.replaceWith(newButton, popup)
  })
}

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById('newPopup').classList.toggle('show');
}
```

```css
.popup {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1.2em;
  user-select: none;
}

.popup .popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: -108px;
}
.popup .popuptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

span.popuptext.show {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<p>This is just example text used to fill this element. This text has no meaning and only serves as placeholder content.</p>

<button type="button" class="class class2 class3"><i class="fas fa-check fa-fw"></i> Button 1</button>
<button type="button" class="class class2 class3" data-overwrite-fields="1"><i class="fas fa-check fa-fw"></i> Submit</button>

<p>This is just example text used to fill this element. This text has no meaning and only serves as placeholder content.</p>

<button type="button" class="class class2 class3" onclick="_ReplaceButton()">Swap Button</button>
```

Initially the button will do nothing (it likely has an event listener already attached to it, which is irrelevant here as that is removed when the element is cloned). After clicking `Swap Button`, the old button is removed and the new one runs `myFunction()` and displays the popup.